# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression in jQuery 1.12.4 from 1.7.1js

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.7

```
$("body").on("click", "$[id *= ddlHour]",
        function () {
            ValidateDate();
        }
    );
```

This is working fine in jQuery 1.7.1 but when I upgrade to 1.12.4 it gives the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: $[id *= ddlHour]

I tried

```
$("body").on("click", "$('[id*=\"ddlHour\"]')",
        function () {
            ValidateDate();
        }
    );
```

but I am still getting the same error. Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to update only to 1.12 when version `3.something` is currently the latest version?

Comment: Hey, it will be less breaking change that why i think
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised that worked in an older version of jQuery, since the selector is invalid. That leading `$` shouldn't be there. It's just:

```
$("body").on("click", "[id *= ddlHour]",
//                     ^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− No $ here
    function () {
        ValidateDate();
    }
);
```

More in [the CSS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors).

---

Side note: Unless you explicitly want to prevent `ValidateDate` from receiving the event object that it would receive if it were hooked up directly, and/or want to prevent `ValidateDate` returning `false` to stop event propagation, you could just write:

```
$("body").on("click", "[id *= ddlHour]", ValidateDate);
```